# Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

When Iam Adding Style to Dynamic Created button below Error Occuerd
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: '{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'Background'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Usr.png)

```
  private void initializedynamicButton()
        {
            pnlContent.Children.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
               btn.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("GelButton");
                btn.Content = new
                {
                    Text = "ButtonName_"+i.ToString(),
                    ImagePath = "",
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10)

                };
                btn.Tag = new { GroupID = i };
                btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
                pnlContent.Children.Add(btn);
            }


        }
```

This Error Occurs during the time of Applying styles to dynamically created buttons in WPF

Comment: Provide more details... on which line does the error trigger.
Try debugging the issue by applying different styles

Comment: btn.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("GelButton");

Comment: From this Line it is happening

Comment: Share the code for `GelButton`

Comment: any Updates please share

Comment: We need to know how the `GelButton` resource is implemented to help you, i.e. share the implementation (the code) of `GelButton` in your question, as already asked.